# Logging bash-history in a database

Tags: bash

Previously I wrote a script which log my previously visited directories to sqlite3 db. I wrote some shortcut to quickly search and navigate through history. Now I am thinking of doing the same with my bash commands.

When I execute a command in bash, how can I get the command name? Do I have to change the part of bash's source-code responsible for writing bash-history? Once I have a database of my command history, I can do smart search in it.

Comment: Not quite sure what more you want than bash's built-in history, but if you really want this, switch to zsh and you can have much more power and control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to come to this question so late!

I tend to run a lot of shells where I work and as a result long running shells history will get mixed up or lost all the time. I finally got so fed up I started logging to a database :)

I haven't worked out the integration totally but here is my setup:

1. Recompile bash with SYSLOG enabled. Since bash version 4.1 this code is all in place, it just needs to be enabled in the config-top.h i believe.
2. Install new bash and configure your syslog client to log user.info messages
3. Install rsyslog and rsyslog-pgsql plugin as well as postgresql. I had a couple of problems getting this installed on debian testing PM me if you run into problems or ask here :)
4. Configure the user messages to feed into the database.

At the end of all this all your commands should be logged into a database called table called systemevents. You will definitely want to set up indexes on a couple of the fields if you use the shell regularly as queries can start to take forever :)

Here are a couple of the indexes i set up:

Indexes:
    "systemevents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "systemevents_devicereportedtime_idx" btree (devicereportedtime)
    "systemevents_fromhost_idx" hash (fromhost)
    "systemevents_priority_idx" btree (priority)
    "systemevents_receivedat_idx" btree (receivedat)

fromhost, receivedat, and devicereportedtime are especially helpful!

From just the short time I've been using it this is really amazing. It lets me find commands across any servers ive been on recently! Never lose a command again! Also you can correlate it with downtime / other problems if you have multiple users.

Im planning on writing my own rsyslog plugin to make the history format in the database a little more usable. Ill update when I do :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Advanced Shell History](https://github.com/barabo/advanced-shell-history) tool to write your shell history to sqlite3 and query the database from the command line using the provided `ash_query` tool.

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ ash_query -Q
Query    Description
CWD      Shows the history for the current working directory only.
DEMO     Shows who did what, where and when (not WHY).
ME       Select the history for just the current session.
RCWD     Shows the history rooted at the current working directory.
```

You can write your own custom queries and also make them available from the command line.

This tool give you a lot of extra historical information besides commands - you get exit codes, start and stop times, current working directory, tty, etc.

Full disclosure - I am the author and maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

Bash already records all of your commands to ~/.bash_history which is a plain text file.

You browse the contents with the up/down arrow, or search it by pressing `control-r`.

Comment: The author of the original question mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `fc`:

> fc: fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] or fc -s [pat=rep] [command]
>       Display or execute commands from the history list.
>
> ```
> fc is used to list or edit and re-execute commands from the history list.
> FIRST and LAST can be numbers specifying the range, or FIRST can be a
> string, which means the most recent command beginning with that
> string.
>
> Options:
>   -e ENAME    select which editor to use.  Default is FCEDIT, then EDITOR,
>       then vi
>   -l  list lines instead of editing
>   -n  omit line numbers when listing
>   -r  reverse the order of the lines (newest listed first)
>
> With the `fc -s [pat=rep ...] [command]' format, COMMAND is
> re-executed after the substitution OLD=NEW is performed.
>
> A useful alias to use with this is r='fc -s', so that typing `r cc'
> runs the last command beginning with `cc' and typing `r' re-executes
> the last command.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns success or status of executed command; non-zero if an error occurs.
> ```

You can invoke it to get the text to insert into your table, but why bother if it's already saved by bash?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the full history either use history command and process its output:

```
$ history > history.log
```

or flush the history (as it is being kept in memory by BASH) using:

```
  $ history -a
```

and then process ~/.bash_history